# Problem with filling input and communication problem with redux in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

There is a base that contains text from inputs:

```
let data={
  textInput:"",
  inputInfo:{size:""},
};
export const loginReducer=(state=data,action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ChangeInputInfoSize":
          if (Number(action.size)|| action.size==="" ){
            let Statecopy={...state};
            Statecopy.inputInfo.size=action.size;
            return {...Statecopy};
          }else {
            return state
        }
        default:
                return state;
    }
}
export const ChangeInputInfoSizeAC=(size)=>({
    type:"ChangeInputInfoSize",
    size
});
```

As well as the component and its container:

```
import React from "react"
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {DataFilling} from "./DataFilling";
import {ChangeInputInfoSizeAC} from "../store/loginReducer";
let MapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    return {
        inputInfo:state.loginReducer.inputInfo,
        textInput:state.loginReducer.textInput
    }
};
export const DataFillingContainer=connect(MapStateToProps,{ChangeInputInfoSizeAC})(DataFilling)
```

Component:

```
import React from "react"
export let DataFilling = (props) => {
    let ChangeInputInfoSizeFunc = (e) => {
        props.ChangeInputInfoSizeAC(e.target.value)
    };
<input placeholder="size" value={props.inputInfo.size} onChange={ChangeInputInfoSizeFunc} />
    }
```

When you try to fill the field, there is no change in the field, but if you replace inputInfo.size with textInput everywhere, then everything will work.
What needs to be changed in the first option for it to work?

Comment: Honestly is quite odd to see the controlled input outside the component connected with redux. Normally I put those inputs, and the entire form actually, inside the component that is connected. Finally the regular pattern is to keep the actions and reducers in separate files.

Answer (score 1):

I guess problem is in reducer where creating `Statecopy`

```
            let Statecopy={...state};
            Statecopy.inputInfo.size=action.size;
```

In first line `let Statecopy={...state}` will create a new object `{textInput, inputInfo}` but in second line `Statecopy.inputInfo` actually referencing to the old inputInfo, so it overwrite `size` in old `inputInfo` and keep its reference unchanged.

I recommend make states flat as far as possible or make sure creating new state.

```
let Statecopy={...state,inputInfo:{size:action.size}};
```

In addition, you can do few improvement to your code by following these steps:

1. Camel case naming is Javascript convention, so instead of `let Statecopy` write `let stateCopy`
2. Dispatch type convention is uppercase separated with underlines, so instead of `"ChangeInputInfoSize"` write `"CHANGE_INPUT_INFO_SIZE"`
3. When declaring a function use `const` because you don't want accidentally overwrite a function, so `const ChangeInputInfoSizeFunc = (e) => {...` is correct. This is true for `export const DataFilling` as well.
4. For a controlled component like `DataFilling` only dispatch the final state, so `onChange` event will save value in a local state, then an `onBlur` event dispatch the result to reducer.
5. Limit declaring new variables as far as possible, so in reducer you don't need `stateCopy`,
6. Make reducer initial state a `const` variable, you don't want overwrite it.
7. in `if (Number(action.size)|| action.size==="" )` first part will be a number but second part will be an empty string. Because of consistency and preventing future bugs make both same. Also you can do this validation before dispatching `size` to the reducer.

Hopefully, all these recommendations will help to avoid future bugs

Answer (score 0):

I had to do deep copy

```
 case "ChangeInputInfoSize":{
        if (Number(action.size)|| action.size==="" ){
            let copyState = {...state};
            copyState.inputInfo = {...state.inputInfo};
            copyState.inputInfo.size=action.size
            return {...copyState};
        }else {
            return state
        }
    }
```